# Invoking .Count on a list contained inside an element of an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, performance, list, count, ienumerable

In my code I have an IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<SomeType> listOfSomething = MethodWhichReturnsAnIEnumerable(param 1)
```

Now, each element in `listOfSomething`, also contains a list of something else let's call it `listOfRules`. I need to return the elements in `listOfSomething` which have >0 elements in their `listOfRules`:

```
var result = listOfSomething.Where(x => x.listOfRules.Count > 0);
```

What does that mean for the performance? `listOfRules` is a `List` so I'm curious to what calling `Count` will do to the `IEnumerable listOfSomething` in terms of whether it will put everything into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `listOfRules` is `List`, querying `Count` property is very fast, because for `List` it just returns the value of private field and not iterating the whole collection each time. Here is an implementation, taken from [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646):

```
// Read-only property describing how many elements are in the List.
public int Count {
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);
        return _size; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `listOfRules` is a `List<T>` using `Count` will just return the stored value it won't enumerate the collection. It has nothing to do with `listOfSomething`, `listOfSomething` will be enumerated and the `Count` property will be called on each list.So there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both yourself and @nikis argue that it will have little impact on performance and I shouldn't really worry. Shoaib is saying that it is bad for performance and I should use Any() instead. Would you use .Any() ?

Answer (score 0):

`list.Count` just returns the value of a field so is very fast. O(1)
So your overall performance will be O(N) where N is number of records in `listOfSomething`.